# Automatically Rollback to previous stable build in jenkins

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, svn, jenkins, testng

I am using SVN for repository.Jenkins for CI.
After Successfully build of a maven project I am doing post deployment test  using Selenium+testng. So if the test cases fail somehow than how to rollback previous stable build in jenkins?

Comment: It's not an answer I know, but the modern way to do it would be by migrating  your source to git and using Pull Requests.

Comment: But i cannot put code on git.any other strategy in which using jenkins this rollback feature can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate parameterized build for doing this. There two ways of doing it.

1) Use "copy artifact" built step together with a "build selector" Parameter to get the right version, then deploy

2) Use a "run parameter" to get the artifact URL, download (ie. with wget) and deploy

The build selector offer three options

- latest
- last stable (works only with "delete old builds" option)
- specific build